# Making a dictionary on R

Tags: r, database, dictionary, indexing

I have a question about creating a dictionary in R Studio. I am using excel sheets, each one giving the visual response of one species of insects.

So I would like to tell R that the excel 1 is about QWERTY insect, from XXX study, from XXXX year, using XXX method. Like a little database. Is it possible ?

Maybe it will be easier to create a new Excel with all this information, and call the data of a specific species using this resume of what data I have? (an Excel sheet with a list of the visual responses I have with their specific information and calling one or several visual responses using an interface ?)

I started investigate the fastmatch package but I understand nothing. I don't even understand if using it is relevant for my problem. I searched also "how to create a dictionary / index / database on R studio" but either it's not relevant or I do not understand. I am a baby programmer x)

I tried to be the clearest possible but I don't know if I managed to (and if my English is understandable).

Thank you so much for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are asking about how to handcraft your own 'dictionary' , a way to record information from your mind to the computer, you have many options, R has vectors, lists, data.frames, tibbles(data.frames with more features) and even environments.
typically tabular structures (like seen in excel) are favoured when the goal is to keep related observations together, you can directly write your own data.frame with the data.frame command.

```
(mydict <- data.frame(mykey=1:2, year=2022:2023,info=c("my first note","another one")))
```

if your question is about rearranging data from one table to another, then you need to understand data transformations, there are good books you can read like r4ds ...